# Quick question on computing the limits of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

### Question:

Since sequences are only defined on the positive integers, this means that they are not continuous functions when written in terms of $n$. So when taking the  limit of the sequence, would you have to change the variable $n$ to the variable $x$, in other words convert the sequence to its equivalent function that's defined on the real numbers, in order to finally take the limit? For **example**, is the following necessary/needed?

Let $a_n=\dfrac{n}{n+1}$.

The equivalent function defined on the real numbers would be $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x+1}$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x+1} = 1$$

$$\text{OR}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}= 1$$

I notice that on many examples of computing the limit of a sequence, $n$ is always used and not replaced with $x$? In brief, I just want to know if it is necessary to convert the sequence to the real number defined function before taking its limit.

Comment: Means the same thing.  By convention, $n$ is used for natural numbers, and $x$ is used for real numbers.

Comment: Yes I know but  would you need to convert the sequence to the equivalent function that is defined on all real numbers (variable x) before taking the limit? The sequence is not continous though

Comment: For example when applying l'hopital's rule you have to covert the sequence of variable n to its equivalent function of variable x. So wouldn't you do the same when just computing the limit, as sequences are only defined on the positive integers?

Comment: The algebra works out exactly the same way, regardless of whether we are talking about natural numbers $n\to\infty$ or real numbers $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Yeah but is it still necessary though? If you were to graph a sequence out, it would just be dots, so it's not continuous. And there is a theorem saying that if the limit of f(x) = L as x approaches infinity, then the limit of the sequence is also L.

Comment: I've seen some examples convert the variable n to x, but later examples always use n. So is it just assumed that when taking the limit of the sequence, the n is just x, in other words the sequence represents its equivalent function when taking its limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limits don't only apply to continuous functions.

The limit of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is $L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon\gt0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N\implies |a_n-L|\lt\epsilon$

Nowhere in the definition is a continuous function. In fact, it's the other way around. We use limits to define continuous functions.

Comment: If I apply l'hopital's rule when computing a limit, I can just apply the rule to the sequence without converting it to its equivalent function defined on the real numbers? I thought l'hopital's rule can only be applied to continuous functions?

Comment: Is your question about L'hospital's rule or limits?

Comment: limits. I'm asking about l'hopitals rule right now because it's an application of limits, so would your answer apply to l'hopitals rule also?

Comment: Technically, no. L'hospital's rule can only be applied when the numerator and denominator are differentiable functions. If the sequence is given by a formula that would represent a continuous function if the domain were the reals, then using L'hospital's rule will work but there is some math to be done to prove that.

Comment: So if the formula given by the sequence is n/(n+1) and I wanted to use l'hopital's rule to find the limit, would I have to change the variable 'n' to the variable 'x', or would just leaving it as 'n' be fine. Of course the computation is the same, but I just want to know if it can be left as 'n' since sequences are not continuous. And also, x represents the function defined for real numbers, whereas n represents natural numbers

Comment: You can leave the variable name the same. It's just a symbol. Our naming conventions are just that.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help